# Product Space constructed from cylinder set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, product-space

I am studying the book "Probability Theory" from Achim Klenke.

In this book the Measure extension Theoremis constructed in the following way:

Consider an infinitely often repeated random experiment with finitely many possible outcomes. Let $E$ be the set of possible outcomes. Let $\omega_{1},\omega_{2},....\in E$ be the observed outcomes. Hence the space of all possible outcomes of the repeated experiment is $\Omega=E^\mathbb{N}$. Then they defined the set of all sequences whose first n values are $\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}$ as $\mathcal{A}_{n}:= \{[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]:\omega_{1},....\omega_{n} \in E\}$
Then $\mathcal{A}:=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{A}_{n}$ forms a semi-ring.

Now they defined a probability measure on the semi-ring $\mathcal{A}$ and want extend it to $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. For that purpose they want to prove first the existence of $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ in the following way:

Define the (ultra-)metric $d$ on $\Omega$ by

$d(\omega,\omega^{'})= \left\{\begin{array}{@{}lr@{}}
        2^{-inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\omega_{n}\ne\omega_{n}^{'}\}} & \text{if }\omega\ne\omega^{'}
\\
        0                       & \text{if}\omega=\omega^{'}
        \end{array}\right\}$

They claim $(\Omega,d)$ is a compact metric space and $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]=B_{2^{-n}}(\omega)=\{\omega^{'}\in\Omega:d(\omega, \omega_{'}) <2^{-n}\}$.

The complement of $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$ is an open set, as it is the union of $(\#E)^{n}-1$ open balls
$[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]^{c}=\bigcup_{(\omega_{1}^{'},....\omega_{n}^{'})\ne(\omega_{1},....\omega_{n})}[\omega_{1}^{'},....\omega_{n}^{'}]$.
Since $\Omega$ is compact, the closed subset $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$ is compact. Therefore $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}(\Omega,d)$, which guaranteed the existence. Applying Caratheodory Theorem, we obtain an extension on the Sigma-Algebra.

Now the following Point I couldn't follow:

1. $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$ is defined as an open-ball, why it is
   closed?
2. Why is $(\Omega,d)$ compact?
3. I cannot see why $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}(\Omega,d)$.
   The Borel-Sigma-Algebra is defined as the sigma-algebra generated by Open-sets. I know it is equivalent to the sigma-algebra generated by closed sets and compact sets. However, the set $\mathcal{A}$, as a countable union of $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$, which is closed and compact, can still not be classified as open, close or compact.

Comment: Your question already contains the answer to your first question: $\Omega\setminus[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$ is the union of cylinder sets, which are open, so $\Omega\setminus[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$ itself is open, and its complement, $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$, is therefore closed by definition.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Thank you Mr. Scott. The confusing point is, as you said, cylinder sets are open, but $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$ is also a cylinder sets, this should also be open isnt it?

Comment: Actually, at this point you don’t even need to consider *all* cylinder sets. The sets of the form $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$ are open balls in the metric topology, and since their complements are unions of open balls, their complements are also open. In fact it’s true that all cylinder sets are open, because the metric topology is the same as the product topology when $\Omega$ is considered as the product of countably infinitely many copies of the discrete space $E$. And that’s also why $\Omega$ is compact: it’s a product of compact spaces.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Thank you! This is very helpful. Since $(\Omega,d)$ is a metric space. So the cylinder sets itself can be seen as open and closed? Why we use here the definition of close? Sorry for those elementary questions, I think I am not that familiar with topology.

Comment: Yes, every cylinder set is both open and closed. (Such sets are called *clopen* sets.) In order to show that $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$ is closed, we need to know what it means for a set to be closed; by definition it means that the complement of the set is open, so we want to show that $\Omega\setminus[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$ is open. We do this by showing that it’s a union of open sets.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Great! Thank you Mr.Scott. That answered my first two questions! Furthermore is $\mathcal{A}$ open? Because I don't understand the point why they use the definition of close. If they leave $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$ to be open, $\mathcal{A}$ is also open as a countable union of open sets. Then the sigma algebra generated by a open set $\mathcal{A}$ is exactly the Borel-sigma Algebra of the space and everything is done. Why they introducted the closure of $[\omega_{1},....\omega_{n}]$?

Comment: $\mathscr{A}$ isn’t a countable union of open sets: it’s a countable *family* of open sets. In fact, it’s the family of all sets of the form $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]$, where $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and each $\omega_k\in E$. It’s a countable base for the topology on $\Omega$ consisting entirely of clopen sets. And since $\Omega$ is compact, each member of $\mathscr{A}$ is also compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you! That's was my mistake. Now I understand. But the third question: how can I prove the equality.

Comment: Let $\tau$ be the topology on $\Omega$, i.e., the family of *all* open sets. $\mathscr{B}(\Omega,d)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$. But every $U\in\tau$ is the union of members of $\mathscr{A}$, and $\mathscr{A}$ is countable, so every $U\in\tau$ is the union of countably many members of $\mathscr{A}$. Thus, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{A}$ also contains $\tau$ and must therefore be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$, i.e., $\mathscr{B}(\Omega,d)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Basically, we need to take the generated topology of A and form the smallst generated sigma algebra and this is the Borel-Sigma-Algebra. Do I understand it right?

Comment: Yes. And since the topology is contained in the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{A}$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra must be $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But why can't be $\mathcal{B}(\Omega,d)\subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$. Namely why is $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ not larger than the Borel-Sigma-Algebra

Comment: Because by definition $\sigma(\mathscr{A})$ is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{A}$, and $\mathscr{B}(\Omega,d)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{A}$. Therefore we **must** have $\sigma(\mathscr{A})\subseteq\mathscr{B}(\Omega,d)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is it equivalent to $\mathcal{A}\subset\tau$, therefore $\sigma(\mathcal{A})\subset\sigma(\tau)$.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you Mr. Scott. Again I would like to extend my gratitude to your efforts and your time. Your help was my greatest honour. Have a nice day!

Comment: You’re welcome! Glad it helped.